# Sphinx throws error when I turn on index_sp =1

Tags: sphinx

I needed to uncomment and set to 1 so I can use the SENTENCE option in my query.

However I get:

ERROR: unknown key name 'index_sp' in /home/indexer/sphinx-dynamic.conf.ph

Is that option now deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

The default/commented out index_sp was initially in the searchd block of options, I removed it and added it to the specific index block and it not only doesn't error it works as intended.